# More Efficient Way to Avoid Multiple Calculations #3?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Looking for a more efficient way, possibly array formula for Min/Max down a column.  Not sure if array formulas work with this function as I can't get it to.

```
=ArrayFormula(MAX(INDIRECT("Data!E"&(K42:K169)&":E"&(K43:K170-1))))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(VLOOKUP(K42:K169, {ROW(Data!A:A), Data!E:E}, 2, 0)&VLOOKUP(K43:K170-1, {ROW(Data!A:A), Data!E:E}, 2, 0)))
```

Note that I am using ROW(Data!A:A) instead of simply ROW(A:A) because the range in current sheet doesn't fit that of sheet Data!.

Here is my current code copied down columns in my sheet.

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("Data!E"&(K42-1)&":E"&(K43-1)))
```

Just need a more efficient way.  Am I correct that using INDIRECT results in slow calculation times.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with some example

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19CJlOeeQoU6ySVIq3msQUUJKeefYpEHv49XSpkp0l8A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula copied down beginning with M42 in sheet1 it is looking for the Max value between Data!E13 and Data!E72.  That value happens to be 2,998.99.  Column K numbers change sometimes so for that reason I need to still have the formula reference column K for row numbers.  Thanks!  Please let me know if you need more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 INDIRECT("Data!E"&K42&":E"&MAX(K42:K))&","&IF(MOD(ROW(
 INDIRECT("Data!A1:A"&COUNTA(L42:L)*K41)), K41)=0, "♦", ),,999^99), "♦")), ","), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0)),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(L42:L),
 "max(Col"&ROW(A42:A)-ROW(A42)+1&")", ))&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That is incredible.  Receiving error message "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col212" in actual sheet"

Comment: well, can't rly say what went wrong in your actual sheet. I would need to debug it. double-check the range references. also make sure that you have at least ~ 500 rows

Comment: Decided to share a copy of my entire project saved 2019-04-06. Cell M42 is what we are trying to change to an array formula. Actually trying to make everything in the sheet better.  I think lack of using array formulas is common mistake that is causing me calculation time.
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RHeqT58QutYUwLcjl48giil4ysoewu8t_-ZxdwRFpNs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I need to change all formulas in row 42 to array.  Some of those rows have a different formula in the bottom row just to start the column out with the correct data.

Comment: I couldn't find the formula/error/scenario from the answer

Comment: How odd.  My active sheet which shouldn't be any different is showing the error and the shared copy is not.  I will mark this as answer and just need to try and see what is different between the two sheets.  Thank you very much!

Comment: How can I get the min instead of the max.  Tried simple changing max to min, but that didn't work.  Thanks!